# Bluetooth Symbol in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: bluetooth, 14.10

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad.

Without further configuration bluetooth gets enabled every I boot up the machine. I can disable it using

```
echo disable > /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth
```

or (using tlp)

```
bluetooth off
```

(which I can also include to /etc/rc.local).

Either version prevents bluetooth to start up at boot. Unfortunately, they also hide the bluetooth symbol. The symbol re-appears if I do `bluetooth on` and it stays visible if I disable it again using `bluetooth off`.

The effect is the same if I include `rfkill block bluetooth` in /etc/rc.local.

Is there a way to disable bluetooth at boot and keep the symbol visible? I could also accept a solution where the symbol stays visible but the bluetooth state get maintained over a reboot (instead of always disabling it), but I would like to avoid a hack like includinig `bluetooth on & bluetooth off` in a login script (think of booting the computer in an airplane...).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem seems to be gone in 15.04.